# Error importing module - ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application

Tags: python, django

I created a Django project with an app named `auth` originally, but ran into some errors and changed it to `authentication`. Later, when trying to `runserver` I found out I couldn't because of the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'coolwebsite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'No module named 'django.contrib.authentication''
```

So I looked online and it turned out I shouldn't be naming apps with the same names as Django's app structure. I changed `authentication` to `oauth` and I'm still receiving the same error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'coolwebsite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'No module named 'django.contrib.oauth''
```

I changed the app name to `birds`, but still I would get the same error. I don't understand why I am still receiving this error.

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 147, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 28, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 57, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\coolwebsite\coolwebsite\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'coolwebsite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'No module named 'django.contrib.oauth''
```

My installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ###APPS###
    'oauth.apps.OauthConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]
```

Why is it that I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because neither of those modules exist. The app is named "django.contrib.auth".

Comment: Why is it searching for `django.contrib.oauth`? My app is called oauth and is not in the contrib packages

Comment: What do you have in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I just added my installed apps in the question. Also, it is worth noting that I am overriding the `django.contrib.auth` User model with my own: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'oauth.User'` in settings

Comment: You definitely have a reference to django.contrib.oauth somewhere. Is it in your middleware settings?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I guess when I was doing the refactoring when I had the app named as auth PyCharm just replaced it with oauth when I changed the app name again